pd.date_range with enddate included
Using pandas 2.2.2 and python 3.11, why doesn't this give me the daterange containing the end date:
import pandas as pd

start_date = pd.to_datetime('2023-04-05T04:01:40Z')
end_date = pd.to_datetime('2024-04-15T00:00:00Z')
full_date_range = pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date, freq='1M', inclusive='both')
for date in full_date_range.to_list():
    print(date)

It gives me:
2023-04-30 04:01:40+00:00
2023-05-31 04:01:40+00:00
2023-06-30 04:01:40+00:00
2023-07-31 04:01:40+00:00
2023-08-31 04:01:40+00:00
2023-09-30 04:01:40+00:00
2023-10-31 04:01:40+00:00
2023-11-30 04:01:40+00:00
2023-12-31 04:01:40+00:00
2024-01-31 04:01:40+00:00
2024-02-29 04:01:40+00:00
2024-03-31 04:01:40+00:00

and it stops at the end of march. I thought inclusive would give me an added entry of
2024-04-30 04:01:40+00:00

as this would include my enddate as well (at least this is how I understand the inclusive argument)

Why do you expect it to give a date which is after the end_date?

@MGP because then my enddate would be included in the 1 month span ranging from end of march to end of april? What should I expect?

Added an answer, hope it will help.

It works as intended.
include only specifies whether to include left, right, both or none of the interval boundaries. Your expected date 2024-04-30 is not in the interval (2023-04-05; 2024-04-15) so the last date is 2024-03-31. You would have to change end_date to a date after it to get what you want.
freq doesn't matter in this case, as 2024-03-31+1M is outside of interval.
Edit: Example where it matters whether to include boundaries or not
import pandas as pd

start_date = pd.to_datetime('2023-04-05T04:01:40Z')
end_date = pd.to_datetime('2024-04-30T04:01:40Z')
full_date_range = pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date, freq='1M', inclusive='left')
for date in full_date_range.to_list():
    print(date)

Doesn't include 2024-04-30
import pandas as pd

start_date = pd.to_datetime('2023-04-05T04:01:40Z')
end_date = pd.to_datetime('2024-04-30T04:01:40Z')
full_date_range = pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date, freq='1M', inclusive='both')
for date in full_date_range.to_list():
    print(date)

Does include 2024-04-30
I also changed time, because include only cares about one specific point in time. In this case, it's seconds.

I think I got this one twisted. I thought interval was refering to the interval I put in. Can you make an example which shows a timerange for which changing the include would make a difference?

pd.date_range(start='2024-01-31', end='2024-05-31', freq='1M') will demonstrate the use of all the possible values of inclusive.

So basically it only matters if the timepoint in seconds matches the exact boundary created by data_range?

Yes, exactly that.

Pandas' Date range compares the created dates to the end_date up to the second. Create dates repeatedly until the created date is greater than end_date. If you look at your example, you can see the boundary at the moment the end date hits the minute, like this:
start_date = pd.to_datetime('2023-04-05T04:01:40Z')
end_date = pd.to_datetime('2024-04-30T04:01:40Z')
left_date_range = pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date, freq='1M', inclusive='left')
print(f"{left_date_range=}")
full_date_range = pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date, freq='1M') # default is inclusive='both'
print(f"{full_date_range=}")

left_date_range=DatetimeIndex(['2023-04-30 04:01:40+00:00', '2023-05-31 04:01:40+00:00',
               '2023-06-30 04:01:40+00:00', '2023-07-31 04:01:40+00:00',
               '2023-08-31 04:01:40+00:00', '2023-09-30 04:01:40+00:00',
               '2023-10-31 04:01:40+00:00', '2023-11-30 04:01:40+00:00',
               '2023-12-31 04:01:40+00:00', '2024-01-31 04:01:40+00:00',
               '2024-02-29 04:01:40+00:00', '2024-03-31 04:01:40+00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns, UTC]', freq='ME')

full_date_range=DatetimeIndex(['2023-04-30 04:01:40+00:00', '2023-05-31 04:01:40+00:00',
               '2023-06-30 04:01:40+00:00', '2023-07-31 04:01:40+00:00',
               '2023-08-31 04:01:40+00:00', '2023-09-30 04:01:40+00:00',
               '2023-10-31 04:01:40+00:00', '2023-11-30 04:01:40+00:00',
               '2023-12-31 04:01:40+00:00', '2024-01-31 04:01:40+00:00',
               '2024-02-29 04:01:40+00:00', '2024-03-31 04:01:40+00:00',
               '2024-04-30 04:01:40+00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns, UTC]', freq='ME')


Now I get a hold of it... Is there a way for it to generate the last entry past the enddate as well? Or would I have to adapt the enddate?

Logically speaking, you have to extend the end_date. You want a date from a bigger interval, so it's natural to make it larger.

pd.offsets.MonthEnd(1):
This method ensures that the end date is extended to the end of the next month, regardless of whether the end date is the last day of the month or not.
Below is the code for same:
import pandas as pd

start_date = pd.to_datetime('2023-04-05T04:01:40Z')

end_date = pd.to_datetime('2024-04-30T04:01:40Z')

extended_end_date = end_date + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(1)

full_date_range = pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=extended_end_date, freq='1M')

full_date_range = full_date_range[full_date_range <= end_date]

for date in full_date_range.to_list():
    print(date)


What's the point of extending the end date if you then remove the extra value that it produces?

import pandas as pd
start_date = pd.to_datetime('2023-04-05T04:01:40Z')
end_date = pd.to_datetime('2024-04-30T04:01:40Z')
full_date_range = pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date, freq='1M')
for date in full_date_range.to_list():
print(date)
